# Вывод размера товара WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста как можно вывести в wordpress WooCommerce перечень размеров обуви(например) в таком вот виде - [image: пример размеров]

искал плагины - но ничего подобного не смог найти((

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

```
function add_atribute() {
 global $product;
 $size = $product->get_attribute('pa_size');
 echo $size;
}

add_action('hook_where_you_whant_show_attr' , 'add_atribute');
```

Обратите внимание на get_attributes() в вашем случае полагаю нужен он.

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас кастомный шаблон, где не прописан кусок кода для вывода шаблона, то ответ выше вам подойдет, только учтите, что в коде `pa_size` отвечает за тот атрибут, который вы собственно выводите.

Если у вас дефолтный вариант шаблона с woocommerce, то скорее всего там уже есть данный вариант вывода аттрибутов, вам нужно всего лишь создать их в админке и задать правила (в вашем случае размеры обуви) `Woocommerce-Аттрибуты- ...`

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).